# Lucene.Net - weird behaviour in different servers

Tags: lucene.net

I was writing a search for one of our sites: (SITE A)

```
    BooleanQuery booleanQuery = new BooleanQuery();

    foreach (var field in fields)
    {
        QueryParser qp = new QueryParser(field, new StandardAnalyzer());
        Query query = qp.Parse(search.ToLower() + "*");
        if (field.Contains("Title")) { query.SetBoost((float)1.8); }
        booleanQuery.Add(query, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);  
    }

    // CODE DIFFERENCE IS HERE
    Query query2 = new TermQuery(new Term("StateProperties.IsActive", "True"));
    booleanQuery.Add(query2, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
    // END CODE DIFFERENCE

    Lucene.Net.Search.TopScoreDocCollector collector = Lucene.Net.Search.TopScoreDocCollector.create(21, true);

    searcher.Search(booleanQuery, collector);
    hits = collector.TopDocs().scoreDocs;
```

this was working as expected.
since we own a few sites, and they use the same skeleton,
i uploaded the search to another site ( SITE B )
but the search stopped returning results.
after playing a round a bit with the code, i managed to make it work like so: (showing only the rewriten lines of code)

```
QueryParser qp2 = new QueryParser("StateProperties.IsActive", new StandardAnalyzer());
Query query2 = qp2.Parse("True");
booleanQuery.Add(query2, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
```

anyone knows why this is happening ?
i have checked the `Lucene` dll version, and its the same version in both sites (2.9.2.2)

is the code i have written in SITE A wrong ? is SITE B code wrong ?
is this my fault at all ? can production server infulance something like this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't they have individual indexes on disk? If they have been indexed differently, they would also return different results. One thing that comes to mind is if there is some sort of case sensitivity that matters, becayse a TermQuery will look for an EXACT match, where as the parser will try to tokenize/filter the search term according to the analyzer (and probably search for "true" instead of "True".

Comment: they do have individual indexes ( totaly diffrent sites, with same functions ) but, they were indexed the same way and the data is the same. you could look at it as if i indexed `BOOK A` in both of the indexes, in the same way, with the same properties, but one works, while the other does not.

Comment: Are both recently reindexed? Meaning, deleted a docs and rebuilt it again? Because old indexed entries will not change if you modify the indexing procedure but not reindex the whole thing, but that you probably know. I'm just guessing that it's the analyzer part of your new code that make it work, and that conclude some sort of difference in the indexed documents. Have you inspected the data using Luke?

Comment: jishi is right, the reason it doesnt work with your original code is because you dont parse "True" with the QueryParser, that will process it with the StandardAnalyzer, which will transform it to "true" (lower case)

Comment: @JfBeaulac - The first code should work, i wrote the second one to fix the problem... so your explanation is wrong... i know the standardanalyzer will tranform it to lowercase...
jishi - i have looked over and over on the data, there is NO diffrence at all.

Comment: Luke doesn't show you the actual indexed terms. I suggest that you actually COPY the index from one server to the other and see if it behaves differently, if you have that possibility.

Comment: @Dementic what im saying is that if your first code does not work, but the second does, the only possible explanation based on the code and information you gave us is that your data is indexed in lowercase.

Comment: @JfBeaulac - as i said, the first code works on site A, but does not work with site B, i had to rewrite the code to make it work, that is what i try to understand.